# Display each duplicate entry

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Using Oracle Application Express and I want to display each duplicate entry in a table. I also want to create a column with a value of 1 for each instance of a duplicate.

So with a table:

**Name**

- Chris
- Sean
- Chris
- John

My query should return

**Name Count**

- Chris 1
- Chris 1

How would I do this?

Comment: Like this: `select name, 1 as cnt
from your_table
group by name
having count(*) > 1`?

Comment: I think that will end up with a result like this:

**Name**
-Chris 2

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using window/analytic functions:

```
select name, 1
from (select name, count(*) over (partition by name) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```